# Deserializing two objects sent via ZMQ

Tags: c#, zeromq

I am sending data over ZMQ via Pub-Sub model.

I have 2 class, one is called Class A which contains two string and another is Class B which contains two double.

My publisher program will serialize Class A and sometimes Class B and send them via ZMQ. How do my client program know which typeof class is sent over and cast it accordingly? I tried doing the following code and the messagebox show MsgPack.MessagePackObject.

```
var ser = MsgPack.Serialization.MessagePackSerializer.Create<object>();                   
object unpack = ser.Unpack(stream);
MessageBox.Show(unpack.GetType().ToString());
```

I am hoping to get the type like Class A or Class B and I will do a if statement. If type is class A, I cast it to Class A and perform action required. If type is class B, I cast it to Class B and perform action required.

I have searched 1 hr for the answer but I cannot find. Hope SO will help. Please be gentle with me as I am a newbie. Thanks.

Comment: Look into topics and pub/sub envelopes. http://zguide.zeromq.org/page%3aall#Pub-Sub-Message-Envelopes

Answer (score 0):

You can no do it (safely) with MessagePack as it is schema-less serialization. You have two options -

1. Add one byte prefix to the zeromq message that contains the message type (A or B).
2. use protobuf instead of message-pack, and have top level message type that contain two optional messages types for A and B.